# Python Multiprocessing: how can I speed up many file parsing processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

My problem is that I have a program which parses PDF files and tries to categorize them. After, it has to upload said file to a database.

The database is not the problem, I think it is the parallelization, as it is not fast. Since my program is slower than I had hoped, I want to optimize it.

I have three processes running in parallel which are parsing the files, save the data to a class (with different upload variables) and save the class object in another queue.

Another process is just taking the class-objects from that queue and uploads them. (Since the database has a primarykey on the index it has to be done one by one)
It has to parse around 20.000 PDF files with more or less 30KB of data.

What I have code-wise right now:

```
def main_program(path_queue, parsed_queue):
    '''here the parsing takes place'''
    '''if i do it one by one it takes around 3 seconds'''
    path = path_queue.get()
    sb = sb_object #this is th eobject where I save the upload variables
    '''do some crazy file parsing with the file from the path and save it to the sb class'''
    
    time.sleep(3) '''simulate the parsing process'''
    parsed_queue.put(sb)

def uploader(parsed_queue)
    while True:
        if not parsed_queue.empty()
            sb = parsed_queue.get() #sb is my class object which has been parsed in the main_program
            sb.upload() #it has an upload function in it to upload to the database
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dateien = ['''List with paths to the file which have to be parsed''']
    paths_to_parse = multiprocessing.Queue()
    sb_to_upload = multiprocessing.Queue()
    processes = []
    for i in dateien:
        paths_to_parse.put(i)

    x = multiprocessing.Process(target=upload_sb_queue, args=(sb_to_upload,))
    x.start()
    st = time.time()

    for w in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_program, args=(paths_to_parse, sb_to_upload))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    x.join()
```

How can I improve this code?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited for the code review SE?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this as

- 1st parse
- 2nd upload

So `parsed=parse(file);upload(parsed)` forms a sequence.

Make every sequence a process.

Avoid file access during parsing.
Rather load and then parse in memory.

I would not mix the code for multiprocessing and parsing/uploading.

The multiprocessing could be done in a shell script, too.

```sh
for f in $(ls); do
    python parse_upload.py $f &
done
```

I don't see a need to `join`.

Comment: thats what I have tried, but the upload is based on a primary key which I have to get from the database -> violation of primary key with multiple processes uploading the same time

Comment: OK. Programming is all about trial and error, because the whole universe is :-) Parallel parsing followed by sequential uploading, then.

Comment: thats what it is :-) I mean it works perfectly fine but it need 18h to finish 20k documents and think that could be faster.